# In requests_cache, does the sqlite file contain the cached request time and age?

Tags: python, sqlite, caching, python-requests

Consider the following code:

```
import requests
import requests_cache

requests_cache.install_cache(expire_after=7200)

url = 'http://www.example.com'
with requests.Session() as sess:
    response = sess.get(url)
    print response.text
```

### First run

When I first run this code, I am sure that the `GET` request is sent out to `www.example.com`, since no cache has been set up yet.  I will then see a file named `cache.sqlite` in the working directory, which contains the request being cached inside it.

### The first process will then exit, erasing all traces of it from RAM.

### Second run, maybe 2000 seconds later

What else does `requests_cache.install_cache` do? Aside from "installing" a cache, does it also tell the present Python session that "Hey, there's a cache present right now, you might want to look into it before sending out new `requests`".

So, my question is, does the new instance of my script process respect the existing `cache.sqlite` or does it create an entirely new one from scratch?

If not, how do I make sure that it will look up the existing cache first before sending out new `requests`, and also consider the age of the cached requests?

Comment: It respects the existing or else it would be rather futile, if you look at the sql file you should see the Date column does not change while within your expire_after range, make it 30 seconds, run the code a few times and you will see it does not change until the 30 seconds are up

Comment: Thank you @PadraicCunningham, I think your comment would fit in as an answer. I did try browsing with `sqlitebrowser`, but could not figure out the schema that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's going on under the hood:

- `requests_cache.install_cache()` globally patches out `requests.Session` with caching behavior.
- `install_cache()` takes a number of optional arguments to tell it where and how to cache responses, but by default it will create a SQLite database in the current directory, as you noticed.
- A cached response will be stored along with its expiration time, in `response.expires`
- The next time you run your script, `install_cache()` will load the existing database instead of making a new one
- The next time you make that request, the expiration time will be checked against the current time. If it's expired, a new request will be sent and the old cached response will be overwritten with the new one.

Here's an example that makes it more obvious what's going on:

```py
from requests_cache import CachedSession

session = CachedSession('~/my_project/requests_cache.db', expire_after=7200)
session.get('http://www.example.com')
session.get('http://www.example.com')

# Show if the response came from the cache, when it was created, and when it expires
print(f'From cache: {response.from_cache}')
print(f'Created: {response.created_at}')
print(f'Expires: {response.expires}')

# You can also get a summary from just printing the cached response object
print(response)

# Show where the cache is stored, and currently cached request URLs
print(session.cache.db_path)
for url in session.cache.urls:
    print(url)
```

And for reference, there is now more thorough user documentation that should answer most questions about how requests-cache works and how to make it behave the way you want: https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io